# CAN Bus error frame in PWM driver

Tags: pcb, stm32, layout, can, error

I have a CAN communication problem with my PWM RGB LED driver. I have a controller and a PWM RGB LED driver. The controller sends messages to the LED driver about what the PWM duty cycle of the RGB channels should be. The communication speed is 250 kb/s.

I didn't see any communication problem in my previous LED driver design. But after some improvements like changing the PWM driver circuit of the MOSFETs, I realized that there are some commutation delays in my second design of the PWM driver (both PCBs are originally manufactured).

After debugging the driver, I saw that the CAN ESR register catches error frames. Because of these error frames, the driver responds to the commands late. But interestingly, these error frames are seen only in some of my second design driver PCBs; some are running with no errors. They were both manufactured in the same process with the same components.

When I reduced the communication speed to 125, 100, and 50 kb/s, the error frame did not appear in the debug. But testing in an 80°C environment, the error frames appeared again.

I designed two different versions of the 4-layer PCB of the driver. One is running without error frame. In a hot environment (80°C), error frames were seen in the second 4-layer PCB.

I think that this problem is because of the PCB layout. 800 Hz PWM pulses on the MOSFETs may be affecting the message on the CAN Rx and Tx lines.

Could there be a different reason than the layout?

What would you suggest I do for a solution?

My first PCB layout. There is no error frame in the communication.

[image]

My second PCB layout. Some of this PCB's error frames occur in 250 kb/s CAN communication.

[image]

My first 4-layer PCB layout: Top copper is poured with DigitalGND. Inner layer 1 is DigitalGND plane. Inner layer 2 is PowerGND plane (MOSFET's sources). Bottom copper poured with PowerGND (all GND layers connected at Input Common Mode Choke's leg).

[image]

Inner Layer 1: DigitalGND plane

[image]

Inner Layer 2: PowerGND plane

[image]

My second 4-layer PCB layout. Layers are same as the first one.

[image]

Inner Layer 1: DigitalGND plane

[image]

Inner Layer 2: PowerGND plane

[image]

---

EDIT: Adding CAN Bus circuit
CAN bus schematic circuit:
[image]

CAN Bus speed : 250kbps

Clock source is Internal RC osc (HSI).

Comment: Looks like you don't use a solid ground plane and route over ground gaps, so there are huge return current loops and that might lead to the problems.

Comment: I add my 4layer pcbs' inner layer layouts. Second one has a problem too. Do you think the planes are mis designed?

Comment: Why do you have two ground planes? I cannot see really via stiching between your power and digital ground plane, so where do you connect them together? Normally you go with Signal-GND-PWR-Signal layers for a 4 layer PCB and you NEVER route any trace on the GND plane and only as few as possible on the PWR plane (never interrupt a traces return path, which means never go over a gap in the ground or power plane with a referencing signal trace).

Comment: I connect the layers at the other half side of the picture i shared. At the return path of Input filter Inductor pin. I am aimed that high current PWM pulses at the MOSFET's sources don't  impact the MCU and other IC's grounding. I seperated the planes and connect them only return path pin of the input filter inductor.

Comment: Did you have a look at the CAN lines via oscilloscope? Can you see artefacts there if you trigger the scope by PWM rising or falling edge?

Comment: Please also include a schematic of the transceiver + filtering and termination components. Depending on their value, those caps might be problematic. Also, what's the clock source for your CAN, internal RC or external quartz oscillator?

Comment: @Lundin, I added my CAN circuit + filtering. Bus speed is 250kbps, derived from internal RC osc.

Comment: @OzkulA Running from the internal RC is questionable at 250kbps. What's the oscillator's accuracy? It shouldn't be worse than 1.3% or that's your problem right there.

Comment: @OzkulA - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't actually the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself and don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead please edit the question to add new information. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules.) Thanks.

Comment: With CAN communication issues the first thing I check is the bus termination. When powered off, what is the resistance between CANH and CANL? It should be in the ballpark of 60Ω.

Comment: I see some schematic symbols that I created when I was working for that company :)

Comment: @Jens, Yes. I looked the signals but I saw the frames clearly.

Comment: @Lundin, First I suspected the internal oscillator the most. But in 2 layers, a few of the products with the same card were working without any problems, but we got CAN error frames in most of them. These frames increase in temperature and become unable to respond to the command anymore. But as you said, using an external oscillator seems like a much better option anyway.

Comment: @Seir, As in the schematic I attached, there are 2x60.4 Ohm split termination resistors on both sides.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, Unfortunately, not much has changed since you worked :) I often use your library, Rohat Hocam.

Answer (score 1):

After long attempts to find a solution to the problem, I think we have found a solution.

My circuit layout is like below in the 2-layer pcb card. The problem seems there is a huge current loop when the RGB LEDs MOSFETs are switching. When I cut the RGB side return path and connected it with a cable to the white side, CAN error frames are no longer received.

My circuit layout is like below in the 2-layer pcb card. The problem seems there is a huge current loop when the RGB LEDs MOSFETs are switching. When I cut the RGB side return path and connected it with a cable to the white side, CAN error frames are no longer received in normal temperature. But in high temperature medium, the error frames are continueing to be received.
In my 4 layer design, I receive the error frames in high temperature medium, not in room temperature.
The core of the problem is seems something like the temperature tollerance of the some components used in the circuit.

But very interestingly, in my 2-layer design, I have a card that works flawlessly even at high temperature.

[image]